# Review audit failure for image topic

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I'm trying to review a few first posts/answers. And here comes my first review audit failure. I have no idea, why.

It's about this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801684/cant-upload-android-assets-to-publish-app-in-playstore

From my understanding, this is no programming topic. So I marked it as "should be closed" with off topic. Does this count as a programming topic?

Comment: I just took a look at the highest rated answer. How I have a headache.

Comment: That question had better been locked and closed a lot earlier ...

Comment: Whenever online services break, people rush here to report it. Unfortunately, these bug reports get tons of votes because the issues impact a bunch of people. That leads to the bad edge case of them being used for audits. Not to mention the mess of duplicate questions and "me too" non-answers that we have to clean up each time.

Comment: Now deleted link: https://web.archive.org/web/20161128101155/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801684/cant-upload-android-assets-to-publish-app-in-playstore

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/33577):

> ### Why was an obviously bad post chosen for me to review positively?
>
> Review audits are chosen automatically. The system isn't perfect, meaning that every so often a poor quality post slips through and is upvoted, which the system interprets as a "high-quality" post.
>
> If you encounter one of these: You can post it on the child meta tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support)[disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) to draw attention to it, containing a link to either the audit task or the post, and why you disagree with the audit. ♦ moderators can remove the audit from your history, and other users can downvote, vote to close, and counteract the decisions that lead to it being chosen as high-quality.

Given that the question has been closed as off-topic, you chose the correct action.

Comment: heh, I didn't know there's a way to dispute review audits.  nice.  now I know and can start flooding meta with my disputes on terrible review audits ;-) (I'm not actually going to flood meta, tis a joke)